# Setting up Android development environment again

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I wanted to start entirely from the beginning with the android environment, so I did some very questionable actions. I deleted the Android folder in:

1. `C:/Program Files (x86)`
2. `C:/Program Files`
3. `C:/Users/User/AppData/Local`

and deleted Android Studio.

I reinstalled Android Studio and I found the Android folder in `AppData/Local` but not in Program Files (x86) and Program Files, which I did not expect. So, I'm really worried that I messed up majorly, and am desperately looking for a way to resolve things neatly. I also want to understand why the sdk is in multiple directories ( `Program Files (x86)` and `AppData/Local` ) and why it's needed. Right now, I don't know which directory for the sdk I should specify for `ANDROID_HOME` in environment variables.

Fundamentally, my question is: **How do I start fresh with the android development environment after all the nonsense I've done?**

Answer (score 0):

Android SDK is essential part of android studio. Without it Android Studio is nothing more than a text editor. All the things behind android studio is done by Android SDK (Software development kit).

Here is the guide to configure android studio in detail. https://www.countontech.com/download-and-configure-android-studio-on-windows-linux-and-mac/
.

Comment: But when I reinstalled Android Studio I wasn't able to find the Android folder in Program Files (x86) and Program Files. How do I take care of that?

Comment: If you have installed it correctly it would be there in Programe Files. Are you sure you have not changed the destination while installing it. If you are finding Android Studio in launcher then it is fine else you have done something wrong while installing it. If problem persist just reinstall android studio with its default configuration, don't change anything.

Comment: Prior to installing Android Studio, I did delete the Android folder in Program Files. Could that have had an impact on it not being found there even after the installation?